# User management in the gateway is a good idea?

Tags: microservices, jhipster, api-gateway

I'm working on a microservices platform built around the Jhipster stack, using the JWT security mechanism.

We have removed the user management in a specific user-api, and we also have a specific concept of license, handled in a separate license-api.

However, this architecture implies a **lot** of calls between these 3 components and we are starting to see some perform issue.

And so, I'm considering merging these services to solve the performance issues.

But, given that other services might need to query for user or license informations, and therefore, I'm wondering if it's a good practice to have microservices query the gateway ?

Comment: Your services should not need to query gateway API for user information they should get all they need from JWT token claims.

Answer (score 0):

using microservices architecture is great, the objective is to have cohesion, so if merging two microservices into one is still respecting cohesion, go ahead and do it (this by respecting the fact that all this stay in a one domaine or topic (user-management) )

however if mergin is not an option, why not using graphQl for user management microservice, you should concider this option.

also maybe your performance issue is query related assuming that you are using jpa.

for me I would never use a gatway for other things than being a gateway

there is lot of things that can cause a performance issue. try to look after all best practices on microservices before taking the decision to merge

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, indeed I'm considering merging because these components belong together. My concern is more about having other microservices having to query the gateway to access user/license data.

Comment: don't know if this is good but if you have one gateway and it become overloaded with queries why not having two !! personnaly i have never tried this :) but it seems some how interessting